# php soap response is null, but __last_response is not

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I use nusoap for service file here is my service.php

```
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
function getProd($category) {
    if ($category['category'] == "books") {
        return join(",", array(
            "The WordPress Anthology",
            "PHP Master: Write Cutting Edge Code",
            "Build Your Own Website the Right Way")
        );
    } else {
        return "No products listed under that category: ".$category['category'];
    }
}
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("productlist", "urn:productlist");
$server->register("getProd",
    array("category" => "xsd:string"),
    array("return" => "xsd:string"),
    "urn:productlist",
    "urn:productlist#getProd",
    "rpc",
    "encoded",
    "Get a listing of products by category"
);
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$server->service($post);
```

Generated WSDL file url is

https://doktormobil.ru/cms/soap/service.php?wsdl

My client.php is

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://doktormobil.ru/cms/soap/service.php?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$params = array("category" => "books");
$response = $client->getProd($params);
var_dump($client);
var_dump($response);
```

Response is NULL but in $client->__last_response I have the right answer from Service.

What can be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: With your code snippet, response is `string(41) "No products listed under that category: A"` for me. Are you sure you ain't looking wrong direction?

Comment: You use the same client.php code? My var_dump($response); is NULL
here URL to client.php https://doktormobil.ru/cms/soap/client.php

Comment: Yes, exactly the same code.

Comment: Yes, it's true when I run client.php  on another server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK! I deal with this. As noticed F0G, he have differ results then I. Problem was that PHP cached my WSDL file. When I put

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
```

Everything goes fine. Thank you.